# "Invalid config" while setting up Kik bot through curl POST request

Tags: kik

I'm sure that I'm just missing something silly here, but can someone help spot my misuse of curl for setting up Kik here?

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"webhook": "http://example.com/kik", "features": {"manuallySendReadReceipts": False, "receiveReadReceipts": False, "receiveDeliveryReceipts": False, "receiveIsTyping": False}}' -u 'username:apikey' 'https://api.kik.com/v1/config'
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{"message":"Invalid config","error":"BadRequest"}
```

Comment: Capital False and True are python specific formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

true/false in JSON are lowercase

Comment: Thanks, looks like that was it.